# PHP proc_open() works for cmd.exe but not powershell.exe

Tags: php, powershell, cmd, window

I am trying to open the 'powershell.exe' shell using proc_open. Webpage **keeps loading**. However it works for 'cmd.exe' shell. I don't understand what difference it makes.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
   2 => array("file", "error.txt", "a") // stderr
);

$process = proc_open("powershell.exe", $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    fwrite($pipes[0], "hostname \n");
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo( '<pre>' );
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    echo( '</pre>' );
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    $return_value = proc_close($process);    
    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
?>
```

Working output for 'cmd.exe', why wouldn't it work for 'powershell.exe'

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17>hostname 
GOKPRAVE-WS01

C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17>
command returned 0
```

**EDIT 1**
After observing the task manager I understand that powershell.exe creates cmd.exe in the background. Is there a way I can get reference to child processes in PHP through 'proc_open'

Comment: can you try  `proc_open("powershell.exe < NUL", $descriptorspec, $pipes);`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Hi, I tried it just now. Same state - keeps loading

Comment: Can you verify if anything is in the Event Viewer that may give more information ?

Comment: Google Chrome console gives - 'Application Cache NoUpdate event'. Just that nothing else